# JavaScript / jQuery graduating desaturate HEX colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, colors, hex

Starting from (say) #ff0011 I would like to graduating scale the background-color for each element div I have in page.

The result should be something like:

```
    <div class="div-1"></div> // background-color:#ff0011;
    <div class="div-2"></div> // background-color:#ff0011 -0.2% saturation;
    <div class="div-3"></div> // background-color:#ff0011 -0.3% saturation;
    <div class="div-4"></div> // background-color:#ff0011 -0.4% saturation;
    <div class="div-5"></div> // background-color:#ff0011 -0.5% saturation;
```

Hope the example is clear, I really don't know where to start on doing this so any link tutorials will be really appreciated.

EDIT: i'm talking about graduating DESATURATE colors

Comment: Does not seem possible with plain CSS for an arbitrary number of elements. Do you want that? Or should it work for the first 10 elements only and then be just white? Please be as specific as you can.

Comment: What do you mean by "lighter", do you want to use HSV?

Comment: @Bergi i mean for example #f4f4f4 -> #f9f9f9 -> #ffffff (just for example)

Comment: @Bergi yes should be work for about 20/30 elements if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is using CSS3 hsl an option ? You would have easy (and REAL) control to calculate lighter or darker colors.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/color_value#hsl()

It doesn't work on IE8 and below, but is widely supported across modern browsers.

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<div class="div-1 shaded"></div> // background-color:#ff0011;
<div class="div-2 shaded"></div> // background-color:#ff0011 0.2% lighter;
<div class="div-3 shaded"></div> // background-color:#ff0011 0.3% lighter;
<div class="div-4 shaded"></div> // background-color:#ff0011 0.4% lighter;
<div class="div-5 shaded"></div> // background-color:#ff0011 0.5% lighter;
```

JS:

```
$('.shaded').each(function(i){
    $(this).css('opacity', (1 - i/10));
});
```

Here's [a fiddle demonstrating this](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/YxFcy) made by Sushanth

Comment: i'm not talking about opacity, cause opacity will affect to all the content, i just need to light the background

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/YxFcy/1/ the content is faded, i don't want to fade content

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys, i found out how to do that , thanks to everyone of you, but this is the code i needed:

```
var i = 50;
    $.each($('div'),function(){
    $(this).css({'background-color':'hsl(145,37%,'+i+'%)'});
    i++
    });
```

thanks to @KKetch who gives me the css3 hsl() example!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery or Javascript to get that working ..

**Using Javascript**

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for(var i =0;i< elems.length ; i++){
      var op = 1 - (i/10);
      var fil = 100 - (i * 10);
      elems[i].style.opacity = op;
     elems[i].style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + fil + ")";
}
```

HTML & CSS

```
<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div> 
<div class="div"></div> 
<div class="div"></div> 
<div class="div"></div> ​

.div
{
    background-color: #ff0011;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    border : 1px solid green;
}​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/YxFcy/)**

​

Comment: uhm.. it seems you are joking on opacity, is it so?

Comment: What do you mean by lighter background??

Comment: i mean #f4f4f4 -> #f9f9f9 -> #ffffff for example

Comment: starting from a hex color (#ff0011) until #ffffff gradually